# ROSSerializationException while publishing TFMessage

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When I'm trying to publish tf2_msgs/TFMessage message, I got the following error:

```
0.966600119221
0.967081379774
0.968426689557
0.968817018408 
0.970126572275
0.970582148198
0.971705996452
0.972002006677
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "laser_scan.py", line 103, in <module>
  Laser_reading()
File "laser_scan.py", line 35, in __init__
  self.lc_tf.handle() 
File "laser_scan.py", line 93, in tf_handler
  self.tf_pub.publish(tf_msg)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 856, in publish
raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field transforms must be a list or tuple type
```

It seems that my node can run for a while (I tried to print some field of the messages as you guys can see above), then suddenly get this error. The message is generated by my script below:

```
tf_msg = TFMessage()
tf_msg.transforms = TransformStamped()

tf_msg.transforms.header = Header()
tf_msg.transforms.header.stamp.secs =  float(msg.utime)/1e6
tf_msg.transforms.header.frame_id = "camera"

tf_msg.transforms.child_frame_id = "base_laser"
tf_msg.transforms.transform = Transform()

tf_msg.transforms.transform.translation = Vector3()
tf_msg.transforms.transform.translation.x = msg.trans[0]
tf_msg.transforms.transform.translation.y = msg.trans[1]
tf_msg.transforms.transform.translation.z = msg.trans[2]

tf_msg.transforms.transform.rotation = Quaternion()
tf_msg.transforms.transform.rotation.x = msg.quat[0]
tf_msg.transforms.transform.rotation.y = msg.quat[1]
tf_msg.transforms.transform.rotation.z = msg.quat[2]
tf_msg.transforms.transform.rotation.w = msg.quat[3]
print msg.quat[3]
```

Does anybody have a idea about this? and how can I do to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267864/rosserializationexception-while-publishing-tfmessage/) by [Quang Le](https://answers.ros.org/users/31417/quang-le/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that `tf_msg.transforms` should be a Python list containing one or more transforms. Change your code like this:

```
tf_msg = TFMessage()

tf_msg.transforms.append(TransformStamped())

tf_msg.transforms[0].header.stamp.secs =  float(msg.utime)/1e6
tf_msg.transforms[0].header.frame_id = "camera"

tf_msg.transforms[0].child_frame_id = "base_laser"

tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.translation = Vector3()
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.translation.x = msg.trans[0]
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.translation.y = msg.trans[1]
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.translation.z = msg.trans[2]

tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion()
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.rotation.x = msg.quat[0]
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.rotation.y = msg.quat[1]
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.rotation.z = msg.quat[2]
tf_msg.transforms[0].transform.rotation.w = msg.quat[3]
print msg.quat[3]
```

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0